# MySQL Adding Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables:

Table 1: `staff_incharge` with following columns - `First_name` and `staff_id` (This is the Primary Key)

Table 2: `student-info` with following columns - `First_name` `Last_name` `ID`(Primary Key)
I have another column `staff_id` which I'm trying to make as a Foreign key, but it shows some error.

This is the query I'm using in MySQL Query Browser:

```
 alter table `student_info`
 add constraint foreign key (staff_id)
 references staff_incharge(staff_id);
```

The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '`student_info` add constraint foreign key (staff_id) references
>   staff_incharge' at line 1.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

`student_info` table was created first and then `staff_incharge` was created next.

Output of the following query:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE student_info;

  CREATE TABLE `student_info` (
  `First_name` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',

  `Last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `staff_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `City` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `Marks1` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Marks2` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Marks3` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Total_marks` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Branch` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`First_name`)
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE staff_incharge;

```
'staff_incharge', 'CREATE TABLE `staff_incharge` (
  `First_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Staff_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Staff_id`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimum code - without explicitly naming the foreign key constraint (MySQL will choose a semi-random name):

```
ALTER TABLE student_info
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (staff_id)
  REFERENCES staff_incharge (staff_id) ;
```

Naming the foreign key constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE student_info
  ADD CONSTRAINT staff_incharge__student_info__FK      -- name of your choice
  FOREIGN KEY (staff_id)
  REFERENCES staff_incharge (staff_id) ;
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. Does it depend on the order of creation of the table?

Comment: If you try to create first the constraint, before creating the `staff_incharge` table, yes, it will error.

Comment: Add in the question, the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE student_info;` (and for the other table as well.) The two columns must also have same datatypes.

Comment: I created `student_info` table first, then `staff_incharge` then tried adding the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! The problem was that I had given different default values for `ID` and `staff_id`.
The main thing is to ensure foreign key and referenced column should have same data types, length, attributes, default values, collation.

These links helped:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html
- http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,19755,499517

Comment: Default values do not matter. Existing rows in referencing table (`student_info`) without a matching row in the referenced table (`staff_incharge`) will not allow you to create the FK constraint.